# How to change content inside of info window for different markers?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps, agm

I am working with angular using the AGM (angular google maps) library. I can't figure out how to have the info window content be different for each marker. I want each marker to have its own information to pop up.
Here is my component.html :

```
<div class ="content">
    <h2>Popular Locations around InComm</h2>
<agm-map>
    [latitude]="latitude"
    [longitude]="longitude"
    [zoom]="zoom" >

<agm-marker *ngFor="let location of locations"
[latitude]= "location.latitude"
[longitude] ="location.longitude"
[label]= "location.label"
(markerClick)="clickedMarker(infowindow)"
>

<agm-info-window #infowindow>
    <strong>InfoWindow content</strong>
  </agm-info-window>

</agm-marker>

</agm-map>
</div>
```

And here is my component.ts :

```
previous;
clickedMarker(infowindow) {
  if (this.previous) {
      this.previous.close();
  }
  this.previous = infowindow;
}

markerDragEnd(m: location, $event: MouseEvent) {
  console.log('dragEnd', m, $event);
}
```

Any help will be apperciated, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<strong>InfoWindow content</strong>` with the content you want to be replace. for example If you want to display label simply add `{{location.label}}`

```
<agm-info-window #infowindow>
    <strong>{{location.label}}</strong>
  </agm-info-window>

</agm-marker>
```